# Which memory is used while accessing package of different user?

Tags: session, oracle11g, package

Assuming Package `pack_x` is defined in `Scott` schema and `Scott`(User) grants necessary privileges for `Green` (user) to execute package `pack_x`.

Where is the package data managed when `Green` if initialize `pack_x`, in User Global Area [UGA] belonging to `Green`? or UGA belonging to `Scott`?.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what should happen if GREEN connects to the database twice and executes `pack_x` in both of them? Suppose SCOTT also grants `execute on pack_x` to BLUE: what should happen if BLUE and GREEN are connected simultaneously and both run the package? What should happen if SCOTT is a schema owner account with no `create session` privilege in Production?

UGA is assigned to a session. All the state necessary for the session is held in that session's UGA. A user can only see the state of their own session and no other session.